# Liquibase version 4.7.1 adding ./ for directory which contains schema scripts

Tags: python-3.x, liquibase

Previously I was using 4.3.5 version, and now we wanted to upgrade to 4.7.1 version.
But it's changing the directory path and we are unable to run **liquibase update** command.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you share your liquibase.properties file?